# "select * into new_table from old_table" does not create primary key

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, django-models

Im using sql query to create tables dynamically, so i made `StockSample` and i want to clone its structure but by this it does not make default id as a primary key and auto increment it

Heres my code,

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query= "select * into stock_"+str(stock_id)+" from stocksample where 1=2;"
    cursor.execute(query)
```

What Above SQL Query Creates:

[image: query output]

StockSample:

[image: stock sample]

Model:

```
class StockSample(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(AppUser,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    barcode = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    mrp = models.IntegerField()
    selling_price = models.IntegerField()
    expiry_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Tried This But still it does not make id as primary key:

1. `query = "Select *, id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL)) Into stock_"+str(stock_id)+" From stocksample Where 1 = 2"`
2. `query2 = "alter table stock_"+str(stock_id)+" add primary key id"        GIVES ERROR`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve there? It looks like you are rolling your own partitioning implementation. Why not simply use the built-in partitioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select ... into new_table` (or the preferred, standard compliant `create table new_table as select ....`)  indeed only copies *data*, not really the structure.

If you want to clone the structure of a table including constraints (e.g. the primary key) use

```
create table stocksample_xxx (like stocksample  including indexes);
```

`including indexes` will copy all index definitions which also re-creates the primary key. There is no option that will **only** copy the primary key though.

If you also want to copy the definition of the "auto increment" column you need to ditch the old `serial` column in favor of the [recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) `identity` column, then you can use `including indexes including identity`.

Comment: `including indexes including identity` is not making autoincrement. "ditch the old serial column"  what do you mean by that? and how can i do this.

Comment: Your original table needs to have a column defined as `identity` (e.g. `integer generated always as identity`) in order for `including identity` to work. If you are using `serial` to define an "autoincrement" column this won't be copied.

Comment: Thanks man.. `(like stocksample  INCLUDING ALL);` worked for me